# How can make interactive html from flash using HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, flash-cs5

I have swf file. I want to create interactive html file from swf using HTML5.
How can i create ?
Can any one tell me help me to crate html view?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about cs5 but in newer version you can export or publish as a html canvas application. You may be able to export / publish as an svg.

Comment: http://createjs.com/Zoe